# Get plugin version number octoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I was wondering if it is possible to get the plugin version number in an octoberCMS plugin, and how this is done. i've been looking for this on google but can't seem to find anything on the subject.

I'm trying to get the number in a controller, but if it is possible in any other way it would be great to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jasper de Vries 
you can check the version of plugin inside the `version.yaml file` under updates directory of the plugin.

Comment: Sorry, i might not have been clear enough. I'm trying yo get the number programmaticaly so i can use it for checks in my plugin.

Comment: if you want the version number programmatically use the system model PluginVersion and call the method getVersion to get the version of the plugin code.

Comment: Thanks you very much, that did it.

Comment: This is a low-quality answer. Please provide the code to actually get the version number as it is not a complete answer to the users question

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
 \System\Models\PluginVersion::getVersion('RainLab.Builder')
```

Note the plugin code parameter is case-sensitive.